# Historical reasons for the IRC #channel prefix?

Tags: history, irc

IRC channels have a prefix (most commonly `#`, but occasionally others like `&` or `+`). This # has become a feature of many messaging apps that came after IRC (discord, slack, etc). I'm curious if this was a random choice from the set of non-alphanumeric characters, or if it was motivated/preceded by some other usage.

[This 1993 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1459#section-1.3) sets out the distinction between # and &, but does not contain any hints at the reasoning. Are there any earlier documents on why # was chosen?

Comment: (Unsure if this is the best place for the question--it didn't seem right for retrocomputing or history. If it belongs somewhere else feel free to migrate or tell me to repost.)

Comment: IRC channels used to be numbered, not named, so there's some connection to the `#` sign. But then the internet seems to say named channels were originally prefixed with a `+` instead, and only later changed to `#`. So I guess it still comes back to the question of why did they prefer `#` to `+`.

Comment: It will boil down to "someone liked it that way", as computers as a general rule of thumb don't like one character more than another.

Comment: I think it was used before. One of the characteristic of IRC was to split local and global channels, so two special characters were needed. Like emails, we had various special characters (now we have only `@` and dots on URL, but we had other characters, e.g. for routing (`!`)). We had also more protocols, so probably such characters were already used on some other protocols.  Possibly on some BBS